# Is there a $f_n$ with two local maxima converges to f only one local maxima?

Tags: calculus

Is there a {$f_n$} with two local maxima converges(pointwise/uniform or other) to $f$ only one local maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function 
$$
f:x\mapsto\begin{cases}1-|x| & \text{if } x\in[-1,1]\\0&\text{if not}\end{cases}
$$
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_n:x\mapsto f(x)+f(1/n+x)$. For any $n$, $f_n$ has two local maxima, and it uniformly converges towards $2f$, which only has one.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n(x)=x^2-\frac{1}{n}x^4 \,.$$

It is easy to show that $f$ has two local (actually global) max and a local min, but $f_n \to x^2$ both pointwise, and uniformly if you restrict the domain to a compact set. Interesting, the global max of $f$ occurs at the same point as the local mins of $f_n$.